# How to show the Birthdate in mm/dd/yyyy format if year is separated from it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a modalpopup inside it I have checkboxes,when I check the checkboxes and save the changes there is  a dynamically created table with dynamically generated labels.I have a checkbox Birthdate inside the modal popup which shows the mm/dd only.And another checkbox below it that will show the year only, and will be visible if Birthdate checkbox is checked.
I want to show that if Birthdate checkbox is checked and the save button is clicked then insisde the dynamic table it will show the mm/dd only.And if year checkbox is checked ,and the save button is clicked, then it will show the Birthdate inside the dynamically created table as mm/dd/year.

Comment: how does a checkbox show "mm/dd"?

Comment: Which platform are you asking about? ASP.NET? Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like there's multiple questions here - not sure which one(s) you're asking.

1) how to format a date in format X or Y?
- You can use String.Format("{0:MM/dd}", yourDateTime) or yourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd") or whatever for that case.  Add on /yyyy for the other case.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

2) how to conditionally display format?
- various ways, but a simple one that I think would work fine is to just add into Page_Load the check, so something like: string format = cond ? "MM/dd/yyyy" : "MM/dd"; and then checkbox.Text = yourDateTime.ToString(format);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.text.aspx

3) how to get the display to change on checkbox change?
- #2 combined with adding AutoPostBack=true on your checkbox(es)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx

If you can further clarify the question, in particular what parts of what you're trying to do you're having trouble with, it may help us provide better answers :)

Answer (score 0):

if (!Convert.IsDBNull(oReader["BIRTH_DATE"]))
                        {

```
                        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(oReader["BIRTH_DATE"]);
                        int date = dt.Day;
                        DateTime bd = Convert.ToDateTime(oReader["BIRTH_DATE"]);
                        int month = bd.Month;
                        lblBirthDate.Text += date + "/" + month;
                        DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(oReader["BIRTH_DATE"]);
                        int year = dob.Year;
                        lblBirthYear.Text += year;
                    }
```